# Books/Tutorials/Video Lectures for Linux Device Driver Development Books

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, device-driver, linux-device-driver

Started studying about device driver development in Linux. I came from an academic background. Started with [Robert Love](http://rlove.org/)'s [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329468) to know more about basics. Then started reading [Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/lkmpg.pdf) by Ori Pomerantz. But feels the Device driver books bit difficult to understand. Looking for some nice Lectures/Books that explains the Linux Device Driver Development. A long list will help the readers here

Comment: Look at these 3 articles - http://derekmolloy.ie/kernel-gpio-programming-buttons-and-leds/#The_kobject_Interface

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take a look at this excellent book - http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/. I use it a lot and find it quite good and helpful. Hope it can do the same for you.